# Why are my tactics ratings on chesstempo and puzzle rush different?

Tags: tactics

I just started chess.com puzzle rush today for the first time. My chesstempo blitz puzzle rating is 1567, but I can only get to 16-17 on puzzle rush, which is about 1000-1100. My mouse is bit slow, but still, shouldn't I be reaching 25-27? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Puzzle rush doesn't really correlate perfectly with blitz rating, you see players of varying playing strengths on the leaderboards. But 25-27 on the puzzle rush seems extremely optimistic for a player below 1600 (I have no idea what method you've been using to determine that 16-17 corresponds to 1000-1100, but that method seems very fishy to me). For reference, I'm a player at ~2200 Elo and I can't really do much better than 30.

Comment: @RewanDemontay Maybe I should, normally I only comment if my answer is short enough and I don't need to work on it too much. It's more of a habit on my side than anything else.

Comment: Those numbers measure two different things, so there's no reason why you should expect them to correlate.

Comment: Well,what i wanted to say was the 17th puzzle in puzzle rush,most of the time is rated about 1000-1100.And my puzzle rating (blitz mode) in chesstempo is about 1570.The 28th puzzle has a average rating of 1500-1520.So why am i not able to reach  28 everytime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading the comments, now I understand the question. The answer is simple: **time**. On ChessTempo you don't have a time limit, while on Puzzle Rush you have to answer within a few seconds if you want to make it to problem #25 or above. You also get a 1500 ChessTempo rating by getting right a certain amount of problems at that level (if you get them every single time your rating will go above that), but on Puzzle Rush you can only fail twice, so you'll need an effectiveness bigger than 90%... while answering within a few seconds!!!

There's also the difference in rating systems (each site could assign different ratings to problems of similar difficulty), so, as I wrote in the comments, if two numbers mean different things, you shouldn't expect them to match, despite looking related in appearence